# How can I manage elements dependent on angular $state change when opening a new window on $state.href?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a specific angular view that needs to be opened in a new window without certain elements displayed (header/footer, etc).

At the moment I am achieving this by looking for the current state name in the layout view, and calling `$window.open` on `$state.href`:

**In the HTML**

```
<div id="header" ng-if="$state.current.name !='newWindowState'">
 //Header Content to hide in specific state
<div>
```

**In the controller**

```
//... 
$scope.$state = $state;

$scope.OpenPage = function (params) {
  var url = $state.href('newWindowState' {param: params});
  $window.open(url, '_blank');
}
//...
```

While this "works", the new window opens *before* the 'newWindowState' is applied--causing some goofy behavior where the header & footer are displayed for a few moments and then disappear once the $state change kicks in.

**Is there any way I can apply the $state update in the new window before rendering anything?**

Alternatively is there some kind of angular pattern I could use to achieve the same end? (That is, hiding or not including parent elements on a particular view in a new window, without visible delay.)

Answer (score 1):

try `ngCloak` [like here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)
to show your content after all initialization is complete

Comment: Thanks for your response! ngCloak unfortunately didn't quite get there. It helps a little bit as the header and footer aren't visible for the initial page load, but there is a still a moment between when angular finishes (taking away the cloak) and the new $state gets set.  This causes the header & footer sections to flicker in for a moment before going back to hidden.

Comment: it is weird also that you have header in your state automatically? from where your header comes from? if you don't want it just delete it from your template inside newWindowState route... something weird is happening in your configuration... try to simplify your code as much as you can (but not more ;p)

Comment: Thanks again, the header/footer html is in a _Layout.cshtml file that all angular views are being loaded inside of :(.

Comment: if this layout is kind of server side layout template then create new one without header/footer and make new route (like /headerless/) to use this template instead of original one (witth header) then open new window with `/headerless/` prefix. In other words just switch your layout.

Comment: any luck? did you implement layout change approach?

Comment: As you suggested a viable approach would have been to change how the site was handling layout, that never did get implemented :).